# Can Onedrive be linked to a server based home directory?

Tags: windows, network-share, cloud-storage

At the school I work at we currently give every user a mapped drive to their home folder on the file server, all controlled through Active Directory.
We also have a heap of users using iPads, which can't easily get to their home folder on the file server.
If they use Onedrive they can access those documents anywhere and even edit them through the Office Web Apps.

Is it possible to setup Onedrive on the server to synchronise their home folder (or a sub folder), so that they have the speed benefit of a local server and the availability of a cloud server?

Comment: Something like this?  http://www.ghacks.net/2012/04/24/how-to-add-external-folders-to-skydrive/

Comment: @RyanRies It worth mentioning that the technique you linked to only causes the computer on which the link is made to synchronize to Skydrive. It might be possible to create the junction at login via GPO, but that makes my skin crawl. This does work, even when pointing to a UNC (though both the client and server need to be 6.0 or higher IIRC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We signed up to IAM Cloud's Cloud Drive Mapper last week in our school, and it's working well for us.  We map network drives for students and staff to OneDrive and Sharepoint in Office 365.  It works well for staff at home too.  We use it in addition to the server home drives, but plan to remove these over the summer and just use OneDrive for home drives.  They gave me a 14 day trial and it worked straight away.  And it isn't expensive.  I'd suggest you look at it (I don't work for them!).